# xslt dividing returns number with E

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In xslt when I divide numbers, like

```
<xsl:value-of select="number( $field ) div number( $factor )"/>
```

result value can contain E (10 power) like `8.004091E9`

How to make it return *proper* value => `8004091000` without `E`s ?

Comment: Have a look at the `format-number` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, the output should never be in scientific notation, so I assume you are using XSLT 2.0.

In XSLT 2.0, the output should be in scientific notation if (a) it's a float or double, (b) its absolute value is outside the range 1e-6 to 1e+6.

One way to avoid getting output in scientific notation is to format it using format-number().

Another way is to avoid floating point: for example, in place of

```
<xsl:value-of select="number( $field ) div number( $factor )"/>
```

use

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal( $field ) div xs:decimal( $factor )"/>
```